# Write a program to identify whether a given line is/have a comment or not

Tags: python-3.x

I wanna write a python program to identify if the lines are commented or not
eg.

1. //hello
2. hi
3. //hey

Excepted output
hello is a comment
hi is a string
hey is a comment

Comment: Please take a look at [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a small sample of what you have tried so far so we can assist you with any errors/issues that you are facing instead of delegating your tasks to us

Comment: Use [Python Regex](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp)

Comment: for a simple case, you can just trim the line and check if it starts with //

Answer (score 0):

It's easy in python. Search for '//' in a string, if it is there then it's a comment.

[image]